# .htacces file setings for Drupal and other site folder in same host

Tags: 8, .htaccess

Primary Domain Examle.com is on CMS Drupal 8.

I must to share host with other site on different CMS location `/public_html/othersite.com`.

What must I change in `.htacces` to have access to othersite.com, and not break anything?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder for the new site with your webhosts FTP solution, for example named "drupal-8-site".

Place all the new files in this folder and add the following line to the .htaccess file:

> RewriteBase /drupal-8-site

Try to clear the cache and see if the new Drupal 8 CMS works as expected.

With this solution you don't risk breaking the other site, as you aren't really changing anything in the othersite.com folder.